# Sybase Unwired Platform 2.0 for BlackBerry Development

Tags: sybase, blackberry-simulator

I'm just wondering why I can't run the sample code in the Sybase documents for SUP 2.0. Is there any other resource or sample code to demonstrate Sybase Unwired Platform 2.0. I followed the steps in the document but I can't figure out what is wrong. By the way, I'm developing for BlackBerry devices.

I created the MBOs, then export the generated code, in my native IDE for blackberry, but unfortunately my BlackBerry simulator cannot retrieve the data in my MBOs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working SUP Workspace to create MBO's..
When you are creating and MBO there one screen this there which shows about data sync at place you have two options. 1.Composit, 2.Bidirectional.. there you have to select the Composit..
When you are creating the Blackberry application, you have to include .jar files of SUP and those are located at "C:\Sybase\UnwiredPlatform\Unwired_WorkSpace\Eclipse\sybase_workspace\mobile\eclipse\plugins\com.sybase.uep.tooling.api_2.0.0.201105030306\lib\client\RBS\BB"
UltraLiteJ.jar, sup_client_rim.jar

at the same location, you will find the .cod file copy those and paste at "C:\Sybase\UnwiredPlatform\Unwired_WorkSpace\Eclipse\sybase_workspace\mobile\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.30\components\simulator "

At Sybase Control Center you have to check the connection templates for each MBO there is one connection. So there you have to provide the Connection parameters like: Database URL and Driver Class and UserName,password of Database.

To sync the data from database to Simulator is very sensitive task you should careful about the configuarations of MBO's and Mapping MBO's